# Unable to upload files using PHP on ec2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have an Apache server running on Amazon cloud and I am trying to upload files using PHP, however I am getting

```
[Tue Aug 25 13:19:20.780797 2015] [:error] [pid 5162] [client 120.59.58.80:9613] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(./Page1.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/handlefiles.php on line 8, referer: http://myhost/articles.html
```

My code for the same is:

```
$uploads_dir = './';
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
// Path and file name01
$pathAndName = "./".$fileName;
// Run the move_uploaded_file() function here
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
echo $moveResult;
```

The permissions are:

```
drwxrwsr-x.  7 root ec2-user 4096 Aug 25 13:27 html
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root ec2-user 1222 Aug 25 13:19 handlefiles.php
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone to help on it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check user of your ec2 apache server. use below instruction
ps aux | grep apache

then check user and use this code

sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/html/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem with the folder permission. 
The ./ indicate the current directory that php engine probably have no right to write. 
First try to run the code without ./

```
$uploads_dir = './';
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
// Path and file name01
$pathAndName = $fileName;
// Run the move_uploaded_file() function here
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
echo $moveResult;
```

then specify whole pass like;

```
$pathAndName = "/var/www/html/".$fileName;
```

Comment: HI,  do echo sys_get_temp_dir() and check if you have a permission for this folder